# 'NSDictionary?' is not convertible to 'NSCopying'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to convert the following code to Swift

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Fetch Current Configuration
        NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        self.configuration = [[mainBundle infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"Configuration"];

        // Load Configurations
        NSString *path = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"Configurations" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSDictionary *configurations = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

        // Load Variables for Current Configuration
        self.variables = [configurations objectForKey:self.configuration];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Here's the Swift version:

```
private var configuration: String?
private var properties: NSDictionary?

init() {
    println("Load configurations")
    let mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    self.configuration = mainBundle.infoDictionary?["Configuration"] as? String

    let path = mainBundle.pathForResource("Configurations", ofType: "plist")

    var configurations = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
    self.properties = configurations[configuration!] as? NSDictionary
}
```

But the last line is giving me two compile errors:

```
Configuration.swift:25:27: 'NSDictionary?' is not convertible to 'NSCopying'
Configuration.swift:25:14: Cannot assign to immutable value of type 'NSDictionary?'
```

I've tried various mutations on the code, `as!`, `NSMutableDictionary`, etc. But just couldn't get it to compile. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `configurations` dictionary is optional so you have to unwrap it when you use it so replace this line:

```
self.properties = configurations[configuration!] as? NSDictionary
```

with this line:

```
self.properties = configurations![configuration!] as? NSDictionary
```

You need to add `!` when you use your optional dictionary.

Or you can do it by using `if let` which is safe:

```
if let config = configurations![configuration!] as? NSDictionary {
   self.properties = config
}
```

Comment: this works as well! Thanks.
I posted an answer myself. Changing it to `self.properties = configurations?.objectForKey(configuration!) as? NSDictionary` worked. 
Swift compile errors are the most confusing and obscure I've ever seen.

Comment: You can use safe way too as I mentioned into my answer..:)

Answer (score 0):

dumb dumb, changed to this and it compiles now:

`self.properties = configurations?.objectForKey(configuration!) as? NSDictionary`